# How to make a simple function that changes a value in sqlalchemy.orm

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I have a `Names` table and I am trying to change `names_id` column where it is 8 to 17, this code works with hardvalues I suspect the problem is i.c , but I can't get around python passing i.c to the class instead of i.{column}

```
#trying to make a function from this
 
i = session.query(Names).get(8)
i.names_id = 17
session.add(i)
session.commit()

#my current attempt

def change_row_make_query(tablename, target):
    i = session.query(tablename).get(target)
    return i

def change_row(tablename, column, target, destination):
    i = change_row_make_query(tablename, target)
    c = column
    i.c = destination
    session.add(i)
    session.commit()

change_row(Names, "names_id", 8, 17)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For such cases the built in setattr() should be used

```
def change_row(tablename, columname, target, destination):
    i = session.query(tablename).get(target)
    setattr(i, columname, destination)
    session.add(i)
    session.commit()
```